# How do I calculate the average of an array?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Class Form1
Dim x As Integer
Dim y(9) As Double
Dim average As Double
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For x = 0 To 9
        y(x) = x
    Next
    average = y(9) / 10
    Label1.Text = average
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm having trouble trying to calculate the average of 0 to 9 array, I realize that my code is only going to calculate 9 divided by 10, How do I proceed with calculating the average of the 10 numbers?

Comment: Any use? http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/LINQ/UsingAggregatingAveragetogettheaverageofallnumbersinanarray.htm or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546138(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq...

```
Dim average As Double = y.Average()
```

Another thing you can do with Linq is exclude certain values from your average. Take this example that sets 9 items in `myNumbers()` to 10 and then sets the 10th one to zero. I use Linq to first filter for numbers greater than zero then I perform the `Average` aggregate.

```
Dim myNumbers(9) As Double
For i As Integer = 0 To 8 Step 1
    myNumbers(i) = 10
Next i

myNumbers(9) = 0

Dim average As Double = myNumbers.Where(Function(num) num > 0).Average()
'Optionally, you could also do it this way:
Dim average2 As Double = (From num In myNumbers
                          Where num > 0).Average()
MessageBox.Show(average)
```

It gets even better when you use classes. Consider this class `Thing`:

```
Public Class Thing
 Public Name As String = ""
 Public Number As Double = 0

 Public Sub New (name As String, number As Double)
    Me.Name= name
    Me.Number = number
 End Sub
End Class
```

I can create a collection of that class and the `.Where` becomes even more powerful. In this example I'm averaging `Thing.Number` by `Thing.Name`

```
Dim things As List(Of Thing) = New List(Of Thing)()
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 5))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 7))
things.Add(New Thing("Michael", 9))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))
things.Add(New Thing("Rian", 10))

Dim AverageMichael As Double = things.Where(Function(thing) thing.Name = "Michael").Average(Function(thing) thing.Number)
Dim AverageRian As Double = things.Where(Function(thing) thing.Name = "Rian").Average(Function(thing) thing.Number)

MessageBox.Show(AverageMichael)
MessageBox.Show(AverageRian)
```

**A side note**
If you're a .NET developer and you'd like to learn to use Linq or you simply need an easy environment to test .NET code then I highly recommend LinqPad. I used LinqPad for all the code in this post.

http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

The average of a set of values is equals to the sum of values divided by the number of values. 
You need to declare a variable **sum** to add every value of your array and then divide by 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum all the values and then divide. I recomend using a simple function for it:

```
Function getAverage(y As Double()) As Double
    Dim z As Double
    For Each i As Double In y
        z += i
    Next
    Return z / y.Length
End Function
```

Just set the average to getAverage(y)